# Spring Api: the program is not finding the pat into the controller

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-14

I start my first api project starting by 0. 
I downloaded the start up project from spring initialiser, and I start to code in it. But now I have a little problem. It seems that the main class don't recognise the controller I created, cause i try to put the code of the controller into the main and it works, in the actual status it give me "Path not found 404" error.

Can It be that I must add the controller somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiDispatcherApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiDispatcherApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
import model.ApiModel;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    public WebController(){

    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ApiModel Sample(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "Robot") String name){
        ApiModel response = new ApiModel();
        response.setResponse("Your name is " + name);
        return response;
    }
}
```

In this moment it gives me 404, but if I put the controller code directly in the main class it works

Comment: Please attach your project structure..!

Comment: use @ComponentScan in ApiDispatcherApplication class to specify the restcontroller packages.

Comment: What packages are your classes in? @dassum that isn't good advice, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class it leads to more configuration over convention.

Comment: @dassum with the `@ComponentScan` it works. Thanks a lot!

but one question, why is it not working without? do I mistake something?

Comment: @CiuzBeppe_93 It depends on the package structure you have used in your project. Please refer to spring-docs for further information.https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @dassum I solved my problem in this way:

Main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("controller") //controller is the name of the folder of my controllers
public class ApiDispatcherApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiDispatcherApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Hope I helped some other starters with this post :)

Thanks @dassum!